# How to compute the Hecke operator on an Eisenstein series?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, modular-forms

In my current course on Modular Forms we are now discussing Hecke operators and we are asked the following:
Prove that for any even integer $k \geq 4$ and prime $p$ we have $T_pG_k = \sigma_{k−1}(p)G_k$
for the Eisenstein series $G_k$ and the Hecke operator $T_p$ on $M_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$. 
First of all, I calculated that $\sigma_{k-1}(p)=1+p^{k-1}$. Furthermore, by definition, for $\alpha=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & p
\end{pmatrix}$ we have, by definition of $T_p$, that $T_pG_k=\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma' \setminus \Gamma}G_k|_k\alpha\gamma$, for $\Gamma=SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\Gamma'=\Gamma \cap \alpha^{-1} \Gamma \alpha$. We have, for $\gamma \in \Gamma$, $\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$
\begin{align}
&G_k|_k\alpha\gamma(z)\\
&=\frac{det(\alpha \gamma)^k}{(pcz+pd)^k}G_k(\alpha \gamma z)\\
&=\frac{p^k}{p^k(cz+d)^k}G_k(\alpha \gamma z) \\
&=\frac{1}{(cz+d)^k}G_k(\alpha \gamma z)
\end{align}
where , so now we have:
\begin{align}
T_pG_k=\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma' \setminus \Gamma}\frac{1}{(cz+d)^k}G_k(\alpha \gamma z)
\end{align}
and we want this to be equal to $(1+p^{k-1})G_k$. I don't know how to proceed at this point, since we cannot just take $\alpha \gamma$ out out of $G_k(\alpha \gamma z)$ since $\alpha \gamma$ is not in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: You assert between the third and fourth line of your computation that $G_k(\alpha\gamma z) = (cz+d)^k G_k(z)$, but $\alpha\gamma$ is not an element of $\Gamma$ right?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, this is the flaw. I am going to think about how to fix it.

Comment: OK. Cool. Additionally when you write $\Gamma'\setminus\Gamma$, you are setting $\Gamma' = SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\Gamma$ to be the set of integral 2x2 matrices of determinant $p$?

Comment: No, $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ have a specific meaning I forgot to mention, I edited it in the question.

Comment: I think you should be able to explicitly write down coset respresentatives for this quotient space $\Gamma'\setminus\Gamma$; they should be $\gamma_i = \begin{pmatrix}1&i\\0&p\end{pmatrix}$ for $i=0,\ldots p-1$ and $\delta = \begin{pmatrix}p&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$; then the expression you have derived for $T_pG_k$ becomes $$\frac{1}{p}\left(G_k\left(\frac{z}{p}\right) + \ldots + G_k\left(\frac{z+p-1}{p}\right)\right) + p^{k-1}G_k(pz)$$. I keep getting stuck here...

Comment: Did you notice that I changed something before, there was a term $p^{k-1}$ that dropped, I didn't see it before. I think that changes your outcome into:$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{p^{k}}(G_k(\frac{z}{p} + ...+G_k(\frac{z+p-1}{p}))+G_k(z)
\end{align}
$
so it seems like we are almost there, we only need to figure out what happens to the $1/p$ in the Eisenstein series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hecke operators for $\Gamma=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ can be written down explicitly: if $f\in M_k(\Gamma)$, then
$$ T(n)f(z)=n^{k-1}\sum_{\substack{ad=n,a\geq 1\\0\leq b<d}}d^{-k}f\Big(\frac{az+b}{d}\Big) $$

In particular, if $p$ is prime and
$$ G_k(z)=\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}}{}^{'}(mz+n)^{-k}$$
is the Eisenstein series, then
$$ T_pG_k(z)=p^{k-1}\Big[G_k(pz)+\sum_{b=0}^{k-1}p^{-k}G_p\Big(\frac{z+b}{p}\Big)\Big] $$
$$ =p^{k-1}\Big[\sum_{m,n}{}^{'}(mpz+n)^{-k}+\sum_{b=0}^{p-1}\sum_{m,n}{}^{'}(mz+bm+pn)^{-k}\Big]$$

In the second term, if we separate out the terms with $p|m$, we obtain
$$ \sum_{b=0}^{p-1}\sum_{m,n}{}^{'}(pmz+bpm+pn)^{-k}=p^{-k}\sum_{b=0}^{p-1}\sum_{m,n}{}^{'}(mz+bm+n)^{-k}=p^{1-k}G_k(z)$$
since for each $0\leq b\leq p-1$, the inner sum is just $G_k(z+b)=G_k(z)$.

Now consider the remaining terms. If $(u,v)$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with $p$ not dividing $u$, then there is a unique element $(m,n)\in \mathbb{Z}^{2}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ and a unique $0\leq b\leq p-1$ such that $(u,v)=(m,bm+pn)$: take $m=u$, $b$ such that $u^{-1}v\equiv b$ mod $p$, and $n$ such that $pn=v-bu$.

If $(u,v)\neq (0,0)$ and $p|u$, then there is a unique element $(m,n)\in \mathbb{Z}^{2}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ such that $(pm,n)=(u,v)$, namely $n=v$ and $m=\frac{u}{p}$. Therefore the remaining terms in the expansion for $T_pG_k(z)$ can be collected to yield
$$\sum_{u,v}{}^{'}(uz+v)^{-k}=G_k(z) $$

Thus we have shown that
$$ T_pG_k(z)=p^{k-1}[p^{1-k}G_k(z)+G_k(z)]=(1+p^{k-1})G_k(z)=\sigma_{k-1}(p)G_k(z) $$
as desired.

By the way, it turns out that $T(n)G_k(z)=\sigma_{k-1}(n)G_k(z)$ for all $n$. My guess is that for general $n$, it would be easier to prove this by looking at the Fourier expansions.